# Kangaroo problem

Tags: probability, correlation, conditional-probability, independence

There is a statement in the book *Data Analysis* by *D.S. Sivia* that I presently not understand.

The statement occurs during the consideration of an example concerning kangaroos, first proposed by Gull and Skilling (1984), in an introduction of the principle of *maximum entropy*.

The example goes as follows:

```
Information:
A third of all kangaroos have blue eyes and
a quarter of all kangaroos are left-handed

Question:
On the basis of this information alone, what
proportion p of kangaroos are both blue-eyed 
and left-handed?
```

In the discussion that follows, the book states that our common sense would draw us towards p=1/12, because any other value would indicate a correlation between handedness and eye colour.

Why is it so, that the choice of p=1/12 implicates no correlation between handedness and eye colour and can we explicitly show that for this example?

Comment: What exactly is unclear for you? Assuming independence of both features it's 1/3 * 1/4 = 1/12.

Comment: You need to argue that independence maximizes entropy.

Comment: Why is it so, that the choice of p=1/12 implicates no correlation between handedness and eye colour? (See also my edit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question here is whether independence of two binary variables is equivalent to no correlation between those variables.

Let's see they are equivalent.

For binary variables, Pearson's correlation becames [Phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient):

$$\phi = \frac{n_{11}n_{00}-n_{10}n_{01}}{\sqrt{n_{1\bullet}n_{0\bullet}n_{\bullet0}n_{\bullet1}}}$$

And $\phi=0$ means that both variables are uncorrelated. For convenience, let's express Phi coefficient as a function of probabilities instead of absolute frequencies:

$$\phi = \frac{p_{11}p_{00}-p_{10}p_{01}}{\sqrt{p_{1\bullet}p_{0\bullet}p_{\bullet0}p_{\bullet1}}}$$

From here:

$$\phi=0 \Leftrightarrow 0=p_{11}p_{00}-p_{10}p_{01}$$

On the other hand, as Tim stated, the definition of independence is:

$$P(A \cap B)  = P(A)\, P(B)$$

Or in the notation I'm using here:

$$p_{11}=p_{\bullet1} \cdot p_{1\bullet}$$

Let's compute $p_{\bullet1} \cdot p_{1\bullet}$ (in your example, the probability of a kangaroo having blue eyes mutiplied by the probability a kangaroo being left handed):

$$p_{\bullet1} \cdot p_{1\bullet} = (p_{10}+p_{11})\cdot(p_{01}+p_{11}) = \\
=p_{10}\cdot p_{01}+(p_{11})^2+p_{10}\cdot p_{11}+p_{10}\cdot p_{11}= \\
=p_{10}\cdot p_{01}+p_{11}\cdot (p_{10}+p_{01}+p_{11})= \\
=p_{10}\cdot p_{01}+p_{11}\cdot (1-p_{00})= \\
=p_{11}+p_{10}\cdot p_{01}-p_{11}\cdot p_{00}= \\
=p_{11}- (p_{11}\cdot p_{00}-p_{10}\cdot p_{01})$$

Therefore:

$$\text{no correlation} \Leftrightarrow  p_{11}\cdot p_{00}-p_{10}\cdot p_{01}=0 \Leftrightarrow p_{11}=p_{\bullet1} \cdot p_{1\bullet} \Leftrightarrow \text{independence}$$

**Update with the numbers in the question:**

Here $p_{1\bullet}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $p_{\bullet1}=\frac{1}{4}$. Therefore, by above, $p_{11}=\frac{1}{12}$ implies both independence and no correlation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I tried to explain to Tim, the second part of the question is: *and can we explicitly show that for this example*? With this I mean: using the figures in the example? If the answer is *no*, than that is fine too, but please explain.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what it says is that we assume that both features are *independent*, so [by definition of independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) their joint probability is the same as multiplying their marginal probabilities

$$ \begin{align}
P(A \cap B) & = P(A)\, P(B) \\
 & = 1/4 \times 1/3 = 1/12
\end{align} $$

What [Sivia and Skilling argue](https://books.google.pl/books?id=lYMSDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Data%20Analysis&hl=pl&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q=kangoroo&f=false) is that such assumption maximizes entropy, what is a further argument for assuming independence if we have no external arguments for other choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You (correctly) argue that the $p=1/12$ choice is (accidentally?) equal to that of the joint probability. Therefore, both features are *independent*. This is sound reasoning. But can you also *explicitly* show that the choice for $p=1/12$ implies no correlation for this example?

Comment: @YtsendeBoer no, there is nothing accidental. You are computing joint probability, you *assume* that the two features are independent and it follows from independence. If they were dependent you'd end up with different estimate, but since you know nothing about the dependence, you *assume* independence and such choice maximizes entropy.

Comment: Could we make this explicit by showing that the choice for $p=1/12$
implies no correlation for this example? This is what I really would like to know (updated my question accordingly, sorry for sending you on a slightly different track).

Comment: @YtsendeBoer as I said, this *directly* follows from the definition of *independence*. Are you asking "what is independence"?

Comment: No, I am asking to calculate the correlation and show that it is 0, thus verifying the independence. I don't know how to formulate it more clearly.

Comment: @YtsendeBoer but correlation equal to zero does not equal independence. Correlation says only that there is no linear relationship between the two variables and here we assume independence.

Comment: True, but independence *does* imply a zero correlation. Can we show that *explicitly* in this kangaroo example?

Comment: @YtsendeBoer [for independent random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$, so their covariance is $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) = E(X)E(Y) - E(X)E(Y) = 0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52592/discussion-between-ytsen-de-boer-and-tim).